# So that + modal verb

Tags: modal-verbs

I was wondering if I could use SO THAT + COULD in sentences in the present tense. For example:

> The bed in the room is fixed to the floor so that it **could** not be moved.

Or do I have to say the following?

> The bed in the room is fixed to the floor so that it **cannot** be moved.

Comment: "They decorate it with silver and gold; they fasten it with hammer and nails so that it cannot move." Jeremiah 10:4, ESV. Why do you think this construction might be a problem?

Comment: Why do you particularly want to use _could_? It's much more natural to use _cannot_ unless you are talking about a hypothetical situation - "I think the room looks better with the bed on this side, but it's fixed to the floor, so I **couldn't** move it even if I wanted to."

Answer (score 1):

The actual question text has been edited somewhat misleadingly, and because it's been migrated from ELU I can't easily get back to the original. But as I recall, the two choices were...

> 1: *The bed in the room **is** fixed to the floor so that it **could not** be moved.*
> 2: *The bed in the room **was** fixed to the floor so that it **CANNOT** be moved.*
> (emphasis mine)

Hopefully putting them both side-by-side like that should make it easier to see that #1 is completely invalid and #2 is extremely unlikely, because of the verb tense clashes. The two natural possibilities (with ***consistent tenses*** and idiomatic contractions) are...

> 1a: *The bed in the room **is** fixed to the floor so that it **can't** be moved.*
> 2a: *The bed in the room **was** fixed to the floor so that it **couldn't** be moved.*

Which tense to use simply depends on whether you care about the *current* situation or what was done in the past. Note that the actual immobilizing might have been done long ago with 1a, and the bed might *still* be unmovable when saying 2a (it's *what you're interested in*, not *when it happened*).